# Redefining a (third-party) ClojureScript function from another namespace

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript

I know its not a beautiful thing to do, but I would like to tweak (redefine) a function from a third party in ClojureScript code targeting the Browser.

How (if at all) is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be late for this answer, but consider using [intern](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/intern):

```
(intern 'third-party.core 'foo third-party-mod/foo)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `intern` is [not implemented in clojurescript.](https://clojurescript.org/about/differences#_vars_and_the_global_environment)

Answer (score 0):

In ClojureScript you can use [set!](https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/setBANG) to redefine a function in another namespace:

```
(set! third-party.core.foo third-party-mod/foo)
```